# CodeIgniter Rest Api

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm implementing the api in codeigniter using the restcontroller and format files shown in the gist below, once inserted I implement the Api.php file in the path specified below but when I try to call the api as a test I get the following error 404 not found, what is it and how can I fix this?

**url to call api get:** http://localhost/api/Api/testget

**I have this file (rest controller and format)**
https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/8878fcda16cae2ad45e4b1c9e624f619

**Php Code(in folder /controllers/api/Api.php:**

```
<?php

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');
   

      
    class Books extends REST_Controller {
      
        function testget()
        {
           $data = array("message"=>"RESTfull API sample");
           $this->response($data);
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: I suppose you should use [helpers](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html) for this kinda stuff.

Comment: the link is not accessible

Comment: It works for me but in that case you could search as "codeigniter 3 helpers".

Comment: I tried to look for one of the solutions you proposed but with several attempts I did not solve the error

Answer (score 0):

Write method name as `test_get`. Keep class and file name same, then call (get) http://localhost/[projectname]/index.php/api/book/test